# Trying to use NLTK with Python and run it on Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, nltk, pythonanywhere, wordnet

I have created a chatbot using NLTK together with Python Flask that runs fine on my local Windows environment.
When I deploy my code to Pythonanywhere I run into problems with the NLTK data.
The error shows that it cannot find the wordnet.zip file:

```
Resource #033[93mwordnet#033[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
**NO MATCH**
  #033[31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('wordnet')
  #033[0m
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html
**NO MATCH**
  Attempted to load #033[93mcorpora/wordnet.zip/wordnet/#033[0m
**NO MATCH**
  *Searched in:
    - '**/home/vvephl2/nltk_data**'*
```

But the wordnet data is available at the given directory...
[see directory with wordnet.zip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwNUa.jpg)

Until now I've tried:

- Unzip wordnet.zip in dir corpora
- Put wordnet.zip in dir nltk_data
- Unzip wordnet.zip in dir nltk_data
- re-install wordnet (nltk.download('wordnet'))
- run tests using NLTK in Python interpreter; runs fine!!!
- veryfied the NLTK configuration, looks fine

  > > > import nltk
  > > > nltk.data.path
  > > > ['/home/vvephl2/nltk_data', '/usr/local/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/sh
  > > > are/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data']

What can I do to make the code on Pythonanywhere find the NLTK (wordnet) data??

Regards,
Jos

Comment: Make sure that you are using the same version of Python/virtualenv in your web app as you are using in your tests in the console.

Comment: Hi Glenn, both environments are using Pthon 3.7